# Using php regex to get value in javascript file

Tags: php, regex

I have tried the following code:

```
preg_match_all("/'<span> '+
'(.*?) Reviews/s", $data, $matches);
```

I am trying to get the number of reviews, here is a sample of the $data:

```
'<span> '+
'319 Reviews </span> '+
'</div> '+
```

My script is returning a `$matches array empty` - any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this pattern:

```
/'<span> '\+\s*'\K[0-9]+(?= Reviews)/
```

`\s` is a character class for all spaces characters (including newlines)

`\K` means *keep out* and remove all on the left from match result

`(?=...)` is a lookahead that checks what is following without includes it in the match result.

Comment: What's about a new line?

Comment: @zerkms: the newline is matched with `\s*` and is optional, since it is not an important element of the javascript syntax here. (it is outside the string)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below regex which uses Dotall(`s`) modifier,

```
/'<span> '\+.\'\K\d+(?= Reviews)/s
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aW0sT4/9)

OR

you could use a lookbehind with `s` modifier,

```
/(?<='<span> '\+.\')\d+(?= Reviews)/s
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aW0sT4/10)